# Error in sending mail using ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to send mail in back end it is showing that mail is going but it is throughing an error Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout 
How to solve this error ? Please help me out .
Development.rb code -

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'http://abc.co.in', port: 2095 }


  # config.domain = 'lvh.me'
  # config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true,
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'abc.co.in',
  port: 25,
  domain: 'abc.co.in',
  user_name: 'hrms@abc.co.in',
  password: '****',
  authentication: :plain,
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  openssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  # openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
  }
```

Comment: http call is failing

Comment: share your code

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari development.rb code -

Comment: add in your configuration tls: true

Comment: comment this line openssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  and uncomment this line  openssl_verify_mode: 'none'

Comment: tell me it work or not?

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari still not working . Can you give your mail id so that will mail you the full code . If possible .

Comment: sure here is my mail aniket.tiw@gmail.com

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari Thank You !!

Comment: @Anubhi Golechha your welcome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144032/discussion-between-anubhi-golechha-and-aniket-shivam-tiwari).